# Wait notify infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop

I have the following infinite loop in java:

```
    while (!Thread.interrupted())
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                logger.error(e);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the body of a `runForever()` method for an application. That application has a shutdown hook attached so that a method named `stop()` will be executed when it gets `control-c-ed`

The question is, why does this works? The thread is waiting forever, who does notify this thread so it stops waiting?

Comment: The method u wrote keeps waiting forever. as ther eis nobody to notify it. Why does this work? what is the qn? are u asking why it shoud wait for ever? or are u asking how is shutdown hook terminating this wait?

Comment: Your thread wait until it gets `interrupt`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Javadoc for [java.lang.Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())...

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object. In other
>   words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call
>   `wait(0)`. The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread
>   releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread
>   notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either
>   through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The
>   thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
>   resumes execution.

... so the thread will wait indefinitely as per the behavior you've described unit `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is called. As for the second part of your question, it's also in the JavaDoc:

> Thread T becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the notify method for this object and thread T happens to be arbitrarily chosen as the thread to be awakened.
> - Some other thread invokes the notifyAll method for this object.
> - Some other thread interrupts thread T.
> - The specified amount of real time has elapsed, more or less. If timeout is zero, however, then real time is not taken into consideration and the thread simply waits until notified.

This also explains a bit as to why `wait()` waits indefinitely. The reason it does is because calling `wait()` is the same as calling `wait(0)`, in which case "*thread simply waits until notified*" as per the documentation.

Comment: And which is the thread that notifies? Using notify or notifyAll? Thanks

Comment: @JorgrLavin, `notify()` notifies an arbitrarily thread waiting on the object's monitor, the actual thread (if there are more than one) that is chosen to be notified is is non-deterministic and could depend on your implementation (or it could just be random). `notifyAll()` does exactly that... notifies all threads  waiting on the object's monitor. Found a good implementation example for you ... [Java Thread wait, notify and notifyAll Example](https://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example).

Comment: @JorgeLavin, does this answer your question? If so, please mark this as resolved. Tx.